# Injecting UnitOfWork with dependency on HttpContext.Current

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container, unit-of-work

I'm trying to inject a new UnitOfWork instance into my controllers with every new request.

For that, I'm using the following code:

```
container.RegisterType<HttpContextBase>(new InjectionFactory(c => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current)));

container.RegisterType<IEntitiesUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager(),
                                                               new InjectionConstructor(
                                                                   new Func<Entities>(() => new Entities()),
                                                                   new InjectionParameter<User>(UserProvider.AuthenticationData.User)));
```

The `User` property in my `UserProvider.AuthenticationData` fetches the current user from the current `HttpContext` because it's needed by my UnitOfWork:

```
if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    var authSession = HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionUserDataKey] as WebAuthenticationDataModel;
    if (authSession != null)
    {
        // use saved session
        return authSession;
    }

    // Reload user if session has been dropped
    [...]
}
```

However, when accessing the HttpContext.Current, it's null.

The first call originates from `UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer()` inside my `UnityWebActivator.Start()` method where I'd understand that no context is present yet. All subsequent calls are not visible in the Call Stack but ultimately originate from the constructor of the controller.

Strangely enough, the UnitOfWork gets created but without a User being passed in (passed in as `null`).

Why is that?

Comment: Where is it called from?  There is no HttpContext.Current early in the pipeline of an MVC app

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch The method to obtain the user from the HttpContext is called in the getter of my property.

Comment: But where in the Pipeline?  What calls your getter?  What calls the code that calls your getter?  What calls that code? Where are you ultimately coming from?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I've modified my answer with the info I believe you're asking for.

Comment: You are calling `UserProvider.AuthenticationData.User` just once during bootstrapping. Change your registration in such way that that User object is resolved for each request (currently it is a singleton).

Comment: @Steven How can I set an `InjectionParameter` to use the `PerRequestLifetimeManager`?

Comment: I think your registration is overly complex. Just use a `InjectionFactory` to allow registering a delegate that creates the `UnitOfWork` class with its dependencies. Something like: `container.RegisterType<IEntitiesUnitOfWork>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager(), new InjectionFactory(c => new UnitOfWork(new Entities(), UserProvider.AuthenticationData.User)));`

Comment: @Steven This works, thank you. You might consider adding this as an answer so I can mark it appropriately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your registration is overly complex. Just use a `InjectionFactory` to allow registering a delegate that creates the `UnitOfWork` class with its dependencies. Something like:

```
container.RegisterType<IEntitiesUnitOfWork>(
    new PerRequestLifetimeManager(),
    new InjectionFactory(c => 
        new UnitOfWork(new Entities(), UserProvider.AuthenticationData.User));
```

Answer (score 1):

HttpContext.Current is not available until the OnActionExecuting event fires.

The better question is why you are trying to inject HttpContext.Current into the controller, when it already has a real live dependency on it.

Comment: I don't want to pass it into the controller, I want to pass it into the UnitOfWork that's being injected into the controller. And this UnitOfWork requires a "User" object that's being read from the HttpContext.Current.